# Setting variables in AppController

Tags: php, cakephp, acl

I am using CakePHP 2, and the basics of my site use the [Simple Acl Authentication](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html).

In older sites I have coded, I was able to define a variable in my AppController, and echo the string in my default.ctp (I use this to build my nav menu for every page).  For some reason now it doesnt seem to work for me.  Am I doing something really obviously wrong?

```
//AppController.php
public function beforeFilter() {
   .....other Auth code....
   $this->set("mytest", "raaa");
}
```

and in my default.ctp

```
<?php echo $mytest; ?>
```

And the error message

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: mytest [APP\View\Layouts\default.ctp, line 51]
```

Since I have had other issues with things not working like they used to with Acl, I have also rerun acl_sync and my users/initDB just to be sure the problem isn't something with permissions.  No change.

Hopefully I'm just missing something really obvious and its an easy fix, its been a while since I have coded regularly, keep forgetting things!  Am I forgetting something with the config settings to have this work on my default.ctp?  Any help appreciated.

Comment: You most likely forgot a parent::beforeFilter() call in one of your controllers.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean by this?  If this is in the AppController wouldn't it feed through into all other controllers?

Comment: Not if you used beforeFilter() in one of them, and you forgot the parent call there, which is what most likely you did.

Comment: This actually came up later as something I couldn't get around, I hadn't come across parent::beforeFilter() (or parent::beforeRender()) in my previous travels or in the basic documentation.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work if I put the code in beforeRender() rather than beforeFilter()